# Users with Full Control Only See their forms in library

Tags: document-library, infopath, permissions, groups

I have create four different permissions groups for my form library.

Users: Which have Contribute Privileges

Admin: Which have Contribute Privileges

Approver: Which Have Approver Privileges

Owner: Which have full control

I have noticed that individuals who are in the owner group, such as myself can only see documents which they created, even when they have full control privileges. 
If I wish to see users documents that were created with contribute privileges, I have to be place in a group with those settings.

Is this correct?

It seems counter-productive for individual with full control privileges to have be in lower permission groups as well.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Replace Permissions in SharePoint Workflows, you need to add all permission groups of users who will be interacting with the library.

If you leave out a group, their permissions are essential revoked for the library.

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings on the library. You may have turned on the setting where users can only view their own items, not others.

Comment: Where does that exist under in the Library settings?